# Terminal transfers at ORD

Tags: transit, ord

Arriving on AA at T-3 ORD 12:20pm  Need to transfer to Cathay Pacific  T-5 departs 3:25pm need advice, carry on only Thanks

Comment: What do you need advice on? I can't see a question here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an airside bus that take passengers from Terminal 3 to Terminal 5.

Simply go to the nearest of gates G17, K20 or L24 (or B1 in Terminal 1) and catch the bus.

Total travel time, including waiting for the bus is up to around 30 minutes. The bus runs between 11:00am and 9:00pm